# Use variables for entering passwords in shell script

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script

I was wondering if it is possible to use variables to ask the user for passwords in the beginning of a shell script and enter those passwords automatically when they are needed. For example we have a script that installs an ftp server and mysql. I want the script to ask the user "enter mysql password:", "enter ftp passwors:" , "enter whatever password:", etc immediately after running the script, store those entries in variables and then use those variables when they are needed during installation, instead of interrupting the script and wait for user input. If this is even possible what would be the best approach?

Comment: use a temporary file to store variables

Comment: yeah but how would i enter those variables at the right time? The script is interrupted when user input is required. Could you present an example?

Comment: change the lines in the script to use external config file instead of interactivity.